# A well-known theorem of O. Schmidt

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

> Prove that if all the proper subgroups of a finite group $G$ are nilpotent, then $G$ is soluble.

How to I prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you see the claim? If it is a well-known theorem, then you ought to be able to look it up (or they will have provided a reference).

Comment: You can see the book "Finite Soluble Groups", by Klaus Doerk,Trevor O. Hawkes, $(10.7)$ page $37$

Comment: There is a reference to this result [by O.J. Schmidt here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00013-010-0215-0) and elsewhere I've seen it called "a theorem of Schmidt-Iwasawa".

Comment: I can't see that article. This must be purchased.

Comment: They also provide a reference in the book you mention, but it is not quite clear to me how to read it when comparing to the bibliography. It might be a reference to Huppert and Blackburn Finite Groups III.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Me too :)

Comment: Ahh, it is explained in the preface that [H] is Huppert I, though it is actually III.5.1 in that, rather than III.5.4 as claimed (unless I have an older or newer version than they used).

Comment: In Robinson's book "A course in the theory of groups", 2nd ed, p. 258, there's a nice proof of a more general statement saying that if every maximal subgroup of a group is nilpotent, but the group itself is not, then it is solvable, and some further info on the group is given.

Comment: @primoz Good to have an extra reference, but that statement is not really more general (it follows easily from the one the OP is asking about).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: I can't find out the volume 1 of Huppert on the Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough outline of the proof is given here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schmidt-Iwasawa_theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Outline for the usual proof:

> **Proposition 1:** Suppose that $G$ is a nonabelian finite group and that intersections of distinct maximal subgroups is trivial. Then $G$ is not simple.

**Proof idea:** Suppose that $G$ is simple. Now there exists a maximal subgroup $K$ in $G$. Show that $K$ along with its conjugates contains $[G:K](|K| - 1) = |G| - [G:K]$ nonidentity elements. Conclude that there exists a maximal subgroup $L$ that is not conjugate to $K$. As before, the subgroup $L$ along with its conjugates contains $|G| - [G:L]$ nonidentity elements. Since $[G:K] \leq |G|/2$ and $[G:L] \leq |G|/2$, it follows that are $\geq |G|$ nonidentity elements in $G$, a contradiction.

> **Proposition 2:** Suppose that $G$ is a nonabelian finite group and that every proper subgroup of $G$ is nilpotent. Then $G$ is not simple.

**Proof idea:** Suppose that $G$ is simple. Since $G$ is nonabelian, we can choose two distinct maximal subgroups $K$ and $L$ such that the order of $D = K \cap L$ is as large as possible. Try to prove that the only maximal subgroup containing $N_K(D)$ is $K$ and that the only maximal subgroup containing $N_L(D)$ is $L$. Then $N_G(D)$ is not contained in a maximal subgroup, so $N_G(D) = G$. Since $G$ is simple, we have $D = 1$, but this is a contradiction by proposition 1.

With proposition 2, the theorem should not be too difficult to prove.

Comment: Why need $G$ is not simple?

Answer (score 1):

This theorem was proved in the paper (unfortunately in Russian):

Otto Schmidt, Über Gruppen, deren sämtliche Teiler spezielle Gruppen sind.             Mat. Sb., 31:3-4 (1924), 366–372

See http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=6900&option_lang=eng